I don't know how take weak derivative of norms in hilbert spaces
Let the following be hilbert spaces with dens inclusions $V ↪H=H^* ↪V^*$. Where $H^*$ and $V^*$ are the duals. $H$ has the product $(*,*)$  and $V×V^*$ has the product $⟨*,*⟩$.
Let $u∈L^2 ([0,T];V); u_t∈L^2 ([0,T];V^* )$. I have to show that :
$\frac{d}{dt}$$‖u‖_H^2=2⟨u,u_t⟩$ in the distribution sence on $(0,T)$
And I have no idea how to get from the product in H to ⟨*, *⟩. Please !!
This to me makes no sence since for one $H$ there can be many $V$ for example the sobolev spaces: $H^m_0↪L^2$ so I belive I'm missing some details

First note that the identification $V \subset H \equiv H^* \subset V^*$ implies that, for any $u \in H, v \in V$, one gets
$$\langle u,v \rangle_{V^*, V} = (u, v)_{H}.$$
That being said, we want to prove that there holds
$$\frac{d}{dt} ‖u‖_H^2=2\langle u_t,u \rangle_{V^*, V} \quad \text{ in the distribution sense on }(0,T).$$
We can regularize the function $\tilde u: \mathbb R \to V$, which is equal to $u$ on $[0, T]$ and $0$ outside and therefore obtain a sequence $(u_m)_m \subset C^{\infty}([0,T], V)$ such that
\begin{align}
u_m &\to u \quad \text{in } L^2_{loc}((0,T), V),\\
 u_m' &\to u_t \quad \text{in } L^2_{loc}((0,T), V^*).
\end{align}
Note that for any $u_m$, you trivially have
$$\frac{d}{dt} \|u_m(t)\|_{H}^2 = 2(u_m'(t), u_m(t))_H = \langle u_m'(t), u_m(t) \rangle_{V^*, V},$$
where the last equality comes from the identification above. Moreover, by the $L^2-$convergence, one gets
\begin{align}
\|u_m\|_H^2 &\to \|u\|_H^2 \quad \text{in } L^1_{loc}((0,T)),\\
\langle u_m'(t), u_m(t) \rangle_{V^*, V} &\to \langle u_t, u \rangle_{V^*, V} \quad \text{in } L^1_{loc}((0,T)).
\end{align}
As the $L^1_{loc}-$convergence implies the one in distribution, we can pass in the limit in the equality above and we deduce the desired result.

Thank you. Much appreciated

You are welcome. If you agree with the answer you can click on the "V" next to it, so people would know this question has been answered.
